# The tangent space of a manifold in some given point.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

My question is about the tangent space of a manifold in some given point.

Let $M$ be a differential manifold and $(U,\varphi)$ a chart around a given point $p$ of $M$ .

My question is : Is that the tangent space to $U$ in $p$ is equal to the tangent space to $M$ in $p$ ?

$i.e$       $$T_{p}U = T_{p}M$$
Can anyone help me please ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: More or less, although I'd prefer to say that the two are identified via the differential of the inclusion $U \to M$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You just need to use the definition of tangent space to prove that. By the way, what is the definition you are using?

Comment: Right... And in fact a point of $U$ is not really a point of $M$, rather its image via the inclusion $U \to M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is essentially the same, and is usually taken to be exactly equivalent. In reality, if $U\subset M$ and $p\in U$, then $T_pU$ and $T_pM$ are isomorphic. In fact, $d\iota_p:T_pU\to T_pM$ is the required isomorphism, for $\iota:U\to M$ the inclusion. The proof is easy enough, and is also found in Lee's *Smooth Manifolds* book (prop 3.9).

Edit: If relevant, he uses the definition of $T_pM$ as the space of derivations at $p$. If you're using a different definition (equivalence classes of curves/their tangents), then the proof is slightly different, but still works about the same as you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you a lot. In fact i'm using the two equivalent definitions of the tangent space and the proof you mentioned fits well. Thank you again.